# How to flatten an object property array has array has array in javascript (es6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

Given a tree-shaped object:

- a User has many Roles.
- a Role has many PermissionCollections
- a PermissionCollection has many Permissions

How do you flatten that with javascript to end up with an array of permissions

Something like:

```
user.roles.map(r = r.permissionGroups).flatten().reduce(pg => pg.permissions).flatten();
```

Is that a classic map reduce problem?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (shallow) flatten function:

```
var flatten = array => array.reduce( ( a, b ) => a.concat( b ), [] );
```

You can apply it like this.

```
var permissionGroups = flatten( user.roles.map( r => r.permissionGroups ) );
var permissions = flatten( permissionGroups.map( pg => pg.permissions ) );
```

Comment: ah right that is nice and easy to read. and underscore already has a flatten, so guessing that does the same thing...will try it out now.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that `reduce()` will probably give the cleanest approach.

You can `concat()` together the arrays:

```
const allPermissions = user.roles.reduce((r, role) => 
  r.concat(role.permissionGroups.reduce((r, group) => 
    r.concat(group.permission), []), 
  []);
```

Note that will actually create a new array every single time it returns, so if there are lots of roles, it could be a bit inefficient. To do it without creating a new array every time, you could use `push.apply()` instead:

```
const allPermissions = user.roles.reduce((r, role) => 
  r.push.apply(r, role.permissisionGroups.reduce((r, group) => 
    r.push.apply(r, group.permissions), []), 
  []);
```

Using `apply()` will let you pass in the permissions as the arguments (basically the same as calling `push()` a lot). If you try to push an array, it'll push it as an array instead of the individual values.

If you want to take it a step further and keep one array the whole time, you can use:

const allPermissions = [];
   user.roles.forEach(role => 
     role.permissionGroups.forEach(group => 
       allPermissions.push.apply(allPermissions, group.permissions)
     )
   )

This is still basically a `reduce()` pattern, but doesn't create lots of extra values. If you wanted to use `reduce()` with it, it could look like this:

```
const allPermissions = user.roles.reduce((r, role) =>
  r.push.apply(r, role.permissionGroups.reduce((r, group) =>
    r.push.apply(r, group.permissions)), r), 
  []
);
```

Comment: great answer. thanks for the explanation. i think i prefer ben west's answer purely based on its readability - although i hear what you say re: inefficiency. however we are talking 10s of items in each array...